# Reading one big file vs open thousands of files

Tags: python

I have 20333 files that together make 93M, each one can weight between 136b and 956K. I need to read data from these tab separated files (*.tsv)

I am considering to append them in one file (to avoid opening and closing files) while I download them from a ftp server.
To open and read any file I use the following function:

```
def read_file(file_):
    with open(file_) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.split("\t")
```

Would it be a good idea to improve performance ?

Comment: I think as long as your memory available allows you to load them into it at once, this shouldn't be a problem. It only starts making issues when the program you're running is getting out of available memory because of the bigger filesizes and everything else you do with the file's content within your program

Comment: The filesize doesn't matter in this case, because you never read the whole file. Iterating through the file is memory efficient and fast and won't lead to a memory issue.

Comment: do the "just" 18M refer to the total size of all files together or is that the size of each file? if the files are 18M in total, i would append them together while you download them. this seems to be much easier...

Comment: At least it will save some logic from interating everytime over and over again.

Comment: @WWhisperer It was the total size. Each can be from 141b to 141kb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, concatenating contents into a single file would improve performance -- if for no other reason, because this would allow contents to be pipelined.

Retrieving a series of files requires a significant number of request/response pairs; while the server is waiting for a new command from the client, bandwidth which could otherwise be used is wasted, unless one adds significant complexity and logic to avoid this (running multiple concurrent FTP connections, for instance).

By contrast, retrieving a large file allows the server to continually send content until it loses ACKs from the client (telling it to slow down). This will result in significantly better throughput.

Comment: Nice point about multiple concurrent FTP. My ftp connection was closed due to being out of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the guys have answer your question in terms of efficiency. I just want to add the following:

To open and read files from a directory/folder you could use the following code below.
Hope this was on some help.

```
import glob
output = r"path\to\file\i\want\to\write\too\output.txt"
with open(output, 'w') as outfile:
    for file_name in glob.glob("/path/to/folder/containing/files/*.txt"):
        with open(file_name) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would do it while downloading them from the ftp server, not once downloaded. Welcome to Stack Overflow!